# touchesBegan and touchesEnded detected on another subview

Tags: ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, touchesbegan

i really got stuck in a week about this case.
i have a UIBarButtonItem inside UINavigationItem, the hierarchy is like this

[image]

The BarButtonItem is a wrapper of segmentedControl. The UIBarbuttonitem and UIsegmentedControl are made programmatically, but the others are made in IB.

in this case, i want to show a view after pressing or touching the barbuttonitem. In several thread i read in this forum, i knew that UIBarbuttonItem didn't inherit UIResponder, so i choose the NavigationBar to get the touch, and i define a frame for it.

this is the code i made :

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
 navBar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;
 int index = _docSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;
NSLog(@"index di touches began : %d", index);
CGFloat x;

if (index == 0) {
    x = 0.0;
 }else if (index == 1) {
      x = widthSegment + 1;
 }else if (index == 2) {
      x = 2*widthSegment + 1;
 }else if (index == 3) {
      x =   3*widthSegment+ 1;
 }else if (in   dex == 4) {
      x = 4*widthSegment + 1;
}

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(x, 0.00, widthSegment, 46.00);

 UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
 CGPoint gestureStartPoint = [touch locationInView:navBar];

NSLog(@"gesturestart : %f, %f", gestureStartPoint.x, gestureStartPoint.y);

 if (CGRectContainsPoint(frame, gestureStartPoint)) {
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(segmentItemTapped:) object:[self navBar]];
    NSLog(@"cancel popover");
}
}
```

the navBar was declare in myViewController.h and i set it as an IBOutlet.

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
 int index = _docSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;
 NSLog(@"index di touches ended : %d", index);
 navBar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;
 CGFloat x;

 if (index == 0) {
      x = 0.0;
 }else if (index == 1) {
      x = widthSegment + 1;
 }else if (in   dex == 2) {
      x = 2*widthSegment + 1;
 }else if (index == 3) {
      x = 3*widthSegment+ 1;
 }else if (index == 4) {
      x = 4*widthSegment + 1;
}

 CGRect frame = CGRectMake(x, 0.00, widthSegment, 46.00);

 UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
 CGPoint gestureLastPoint = [touch locationInView:navBar];

 NSLog(@"lastPOint : %d", gestureLastPoint);

if (CGRectContainsPoint(frame, gestureLastPoint)) {
    if (touch.tapCount <= 2) {
           [self performSelector:@selector(segmentItemTapped:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
    }
}
}
```

touchesBegan and touchesEnded was detected when i tap at the toolbar, NOT in the navbar.

i did implemented the hitTest method like this :

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UIView *touchedView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    NSSet* touches = [event allTouches];
    // handle touches if you need
    return touchedView;
}
```

but it still nothing get better.

Somebody can decribe why this is happen?
Regards
-Risma-

Answer (score 0):

you can simply add an action to the barbutton item like

```
[self.mybarbutton setAction:@selector(barButtonTapped:)];  

[self.mybarbutton setTarget:self];
```

Comment: thx for your help aji, but it can't solve my problem, the segmentItemTap action is an action for show a popover, when i try your code, the popover didn't come, i was think about the undetected touchesBegan and touchesEnded in my navbar, do you know why??